# Are there any smart operationes on the elements of list in Python

Tags: python

For example,

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[1,2,3,4,5]
c=[]
for i,j in a,b:
    c.append(i+j)
```

Can I do it like `c=a+b`, Not c=[i=j fori,j in zip(a,b)]

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
th=3
c=[]
for i in a:
    c.append(i>th)
```

Can I do it like `c=a>th`

PS : I don't want to use numpy. I mean can i do it on list like numpy.Besuase it will transfer list to array.

Comment: The standard package for things like this is [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: `numpy` exists, in part, because such operations are not part of the core Python language. In fact, it's probably as close to part of the core as a module can get, seeing as how the [extended slice syntax](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html) was added just for `numpy`.

Comment: You _could_ subclass array and override it's `+` operator, but then you'd still have to declare at least one of your arrays as an instance of _that_ class instead, so you might just as well use numpy

Comment: Why are you avoiding numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> a + b
array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10])
>>> a > 3
array([False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

From the [numpy website](http://www.numpy.org/):

> NumPy is the fundamental package for scientific computing with Python.
>   It contains among other things:
>
> - a powerful N-dimensional array object
> - sophisticated (broadcasting) functions
> - tools for integrating C/C++ and Fortran code
> - useful linear algebra, Fourier transform, and random number capabilities
>
> Besides its obvious scientific uses, NumPy can also be used as an
>   efficient multi-dimensional container of generic data. Arbitrary
>   data-types can be defined. This allows NumPy to seamlessly and
>   speedily integrate with a wide variety of databases.

Answer (score 4):

For the first one:

```
c = [i+j for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

For the second one:

```
c = [i > th for i in a]
```

Comment: I also know this way . I want to konw  any other operations like in matlab

Comment: @Samuel Yes, it is called numpy, whether you like it or not.